# Conditional get request in vue for rendering a subcomponent scoped

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

When I click a profile (of an **author**) component, I can't figure out how it should render a scoped sub-component, listing the main entities of the app, so-called fabmoments (containers for 3D print information).

My current solution looks like this:

```
export default {
  name: 'Multipe',
  props: [
    'author'
  ],
  data () {
    return {
    //   search: '',
      localAuthor: '',
      fabmoments: []
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.localAuthor = this.author
    if (typeof localAuthor !== 'undefined') {
      this.$http.get(`/users/${this.$route.params.id}/fabmoments`)
        .then(request => this.buildFabmomentList(request.data))
        .catch(() => { alert('Couldn\'t fetch faboments!') })
    } else {
      this.$http.get('/fabmoments')
        .then(request => this.buildFabmomentList(request.data))
        .catch(() => { alert('Couldn\'t fetch faboments!') })
    }
  },
  methods: {
    buildFabmomentList (data) {
      this.fabmoments = data
    } 
  },
  components: {
    // Box
  }
}
```

This renders all in the profile, where it should render a list scoped to the current profile's author.

And it renders nothing in the home (without receiving the prop), where it should render all.

I am not much of star in JavaScript. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

This works as a solution, though not very elegant.

```
export default {
  name: 'Multipe',
  props: [
    'author'
  ],
  data () {
    return {
      fabmoments: []
    }
  },
  created () {
    if (this.author.id >= 0) {
      this.$http.get(`/users/${this.$route.params.id}/fabmoments`)
        .then(request => this.buildFabmomentList(request.data))
        .catch(() => { alert('Couldn\'t fetch faboments!') })
    } else {
      this.$http.get('/fabmoments')
        .then(request => this.buildFabmomentList(request.data))
        .catch(() => { alert('Couldn\'t fetch faboments!') })
    }
  },
  methods: {
    buildFabmomentList (data) {
      this.fabmoments = data
    }
  },
  components: {
    // Box
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which part is wrong, but you may definitely debug your code to find out why `fabmoments` is empty array assuming there is no error occurred yet.

There are three parts to debug:

1. http response -- to check if data is properly returned
2. `this` -- to check if `this` pointer still points at the component
3. template -- to check if `fabmoments` are correctly bind to the element

At last, it would be better to separate your http request logics from your components.

Good luck!

Comment: Yes, the get-requests work. Yes, the `localAuthor` is filled when in the profile. I think it's most probably something in the if else logic, something really stupid.

Comment: Perhaps the response data needs to be decoded or formatted. It's possible to check if the data is a list of array. Anyway, the fetch should be working in my opinion.

Comment: No the response is fine, I have a working component in that regard. I added a working solution, but I think there probably is a better one.